# Searching for a sql server database reference string pattern [Database].[Schema].[Object]

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql, notepad++

I need to search through various large T-SQL scripts and find all references to database objects which has **`[Database].[SchemaName].[Table|View|StoredProcedure]`** pattern.

I'm using notepad++ to search folders containing the target scripts. Could someone help me out with a **regular expression**  to identify references to database objects that use the pattern described above. For example:

```
[MyDB].[MySchema].Employee
MyDb.MySchema.Employee
MyDb.[MySchema].uspGetEmployee
[MyDb].MySchema.vwEmployee
```

are all candidates to be found because they have the three layers.

`[MySchema].Employee` is not a candidate because it doesn't follow the pattern of `[Db].[Schema].[Object]`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex:

```
(\w+|\[\w+\])\.(\w+|\[\w+\])\.\w+
```

Is as simple as it gets. It means:

- A word, or a word in between `[]` (`(\w+|\[\w+\])`);
- Followed by a dot (`\.`);
- Followed by a word, or a word in between `[]` (`(\w+|\[\w+\])`);
- Followed by a dot (`\.`);
- Followed by a word (`\w+`).

Check out [this **demo** and see (and test)](http://regexr.com?35jb0) what it matches.

Naturally, just place it in the ***Find what:*** text field of notepad++ search box.